# SublimeText/MavensMate Diff Files

Tags: ide, mavensmate, sublime

In Eclipse, I was able to select two files or folders and `compare with` > `each other`. Does SublimeText have analogous functionality or do I need to seek other applications to accomplish what I want?

Comment: I use sublimerge n its gud.. http://www.sublimerge.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I develop in atom.io and use [compare files](https://atom.io/packages/compare-files) but it looks like Sublime has a very similar package available called [Compare Side-by-Side](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Compare%20Side-By-Side). You will need package control to install it but if you are using Mavensmate you must already have that installed.